# How to self register user with keycloak rest api

Tags: rest, keycloak

Please explain how I can **self-register** users with **Keycloak** Rest API.

I have a **Mobile app**, where I need users to self register. But so far I cannot find any example with proper rest api to enable self registration. There are only examples with Keycloak login page which is not suitable for me

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you tell me how you handled it?

Answer (score 1):

Rest API provided by Keycloak dedicated only for administration related tasks. For self-registration keycloak provide `registration flow` feature (See `authentication -> Flows -> select "Registration"`). If default components don't suit your needs you can apply your own logic inside custom implementation of Authenticator SPI.

UPD. You also can create middleware service that will provide required registration Rest API for your mobile APP via utilizing Keycloak Admin API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to allow users register without admin user interaction. They can do it from the Keycloak Web UI, I guess allowing them to self-register with rest api would also very convenient.